# How many 3-digit numbers that are odd can be formed from the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8}

Tags: combinatorics

This problem is asking how many 3-digit numbers that are odd can be  formed from the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8}

Comment: I don't think there can be repetition. You did not do it by permutations, you did it using the generalized counting principle, in which case there are no two different ways to construct the same number.

Comment: Do you have the original statement of the problem?  "Three digit different odd numbers" is an odd phrasing in English.

Comment: Is 037 a three digits odd number.

Comment: Sorry english is not my first language, it asking how many 3-digit numbers that are odd can be formed by this set of numbers

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No zero shouldn't be in the beginning

Comment: it should be ( 6*7+ 7  )4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just a hint**

$a01$  7 posibilities.

$a03$ 7

$a05$ 7

$a07$ 7

$ab1$  7*7

$ab3$  7*7

$ab5$  7*7

$ab7$  7*7

toal $=224$

Comment: It is clear now it seems like I made a mistake somewhere when writing the set of numbers, so sorry for the confusion, it is 4AM, i think you can relate, thanks!

Comment: Choosing from the set suggests that digits cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in reverse. There are 4 number choices for the third digit. Now there are 8 choices for the second and then 7 for the first. 4*7*8 = 224. (I quess they are allowing 0 be the first digit.) If you do it left to right you need to account for the cases when an odd number is chosen for the first or second digit. In these cases you will not have 4 choices for the third digit.

Comment: Seems like I didn't notice that the number 6 shouldn't be in the set. Tried solving this 4 times, 4 times the same result it drove me crazy

Comment: We are not allowed to place $0$ in the hundreds place, otherwise we would have a two-digit number.  Approach as follows:  Choose an odd number for the units place.  Next, choose one of the remaining nonzero digits for the hundreds place.  Finally, choose one of the remaining digits for the tens place.